# Ember.js: Get information on errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, ember.js

Happily continuing my journey to learn Ember.js, I am creating a relationship between two objects like this:

```
var item  = App.Item.find( itemId );
item.set('stage', stage);
item.store.commit()
```

This produces an error.

Ok, so I added the following to my model:

```
 App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  stage: DS.belongsTo( 'App.Stage' ),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  desc: DS.attr('string'),
  becameError: function(error) {
     console.log("* item becameError");
     console.log(this.get('errors')); // <- this
  }
 });
```

This prints out the "* item becameError" in the JS-console, but the second console.log evaluates to "null".

How do I get more information about what caused the error? ( My REST-API logs show things went just well, the record is stored correctly and when I refresh the browser Ember displays the data as it should be. )

Comment: What was the error before you added `becameError`?

Comment: The actual problem is `Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on <App.Item:ember372:4> while in state rootState.error. Called with undefined ` when I attempt to create a new Item after having some other `Item` added to a `Stage`. I only saw the error when attempting another `createRecord`. Thus I wrote the `becameError` to see it happen earlier and debug what actually goes wrong. Any tips are very appreciated.

Comment: I found my error. In the update one would normally responde with a 204 status code, but Ember.js expects a 200 (which is unusual for a PUT request I suppose). Still, the question still stands. Is there a way to inspect errors in Ember?